# Exp:resso's Store apply coupon to category only

Tags: extension, expresso-store, module, expresso

Does anyone know if it is possible to set up a promo code in Store that only applies to products in a certain category?

I am happy to use an extension (if one exists) to fill the gap if this isn't supported natively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no existing extensions that I'm aware of that can handle this functionality. Currently promo code discounts are applied to a whole order, not individual items.

However, it would certainly be possible to write something in PHP to handle this using the extension hooks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll chat to the client and see if it is a necessity.

Comment: For what it is worth, I think it's a solid idea to be baked into the core of Store.

Comment: Yep, we have plans to overhaul our promotions system (at some point in the indeterminate future) so will keep this in mind.

Comment: Which hooks would you use to accomplish this and how would the add-on know what category to check against? It seems to me we'd have to modify Store itself. E.g. for my own uses I want to use Zoo Visitors & Categories to simular plural member groups, so I wouldn't want to just check if a Product has the category but if a particular member is of such and such category...